# Set background color of entire window in PDCurses

Tags: c++, windows, console, pdcurses

`wattron` and a color pair only sets the background color of text when it is printed inside a window. What is the best way to set the background color of the entire window without filling it with spaces (i.e. a title or status bar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `wbkgd` with a pointer to a `WINDOW` object and a color pair sets the background color of the window.